# How to add conditional classes in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new here :/ ,, trying to create a dynamic blog and the problem is I am trying to change div ID according to words count inside it .. sometimes I get "cannot compare fixnum with string" error and sometime syntax error ..

```
<style>
#smalldiv {
width: 100px;
background-color: red;
height: 150px;
}
#largediv {
width:300px;
background-color: green;
height: 150px;
}
</style>
```

Posts controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
def index
@posts = Post.all
end
end
```

Posts_view

```
<% @posts.each do |x| %>
<div id = '<%= 'smalldiv' if x.description.size < '50' + 'largediv' if x.description.size > '50' %>' >
<p> <% x.description %> </p>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: soft of off topic but html `id` should be unique within a single html document. using `class` might make more sense here and your css would change from `#smalldiv` to `.smalldiv`

Comment: thanks alot for your feedback ... you are completely true and next time I will certainly take this into account ... THANKS ALOT house9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<div id="<%= x.description.size < 50 ? 'smalldiv' : 'largediv' %>" >`

You had ... quotes around 50, too many `if` statements in a row, a missing `=` in your `<%`, and a gap if `.size` equals exactly 50.

Comment: thanks alot IT worked looks like those quotes got me :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `<%=` to output something and `<%` to execute some logic

Comment: Thanks I changed it but it didn't solve my problem  looks like my syntax is wrong or missing something ..